# How to compare two string versions using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

Hi I have below two string

```
$str1 = "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
$str2 = "Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
```

Q.

> 1. If both are matches then it's true
> 2. $str1 > "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" then it's true
> 3. $str1 = "Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS" then it's true
> 4. $str1 < "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" then it's false
> 5. $str1 > "Ubuntu 16.05 LTS" then it's false

Comment: i want to compare only Ubuntu 16.04 version only

Comment: What have you tried so far on this ? There is a `compare-object` but also an `IF/ELse , elseif , else` will get it done. `Switch case` is also recommended for the same.

Comment: Take a look at [`Version` type](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/01/03/pstip-validating-version-numbers-without-regex/) if you want to compare versions. That with splitting the string should do the job for you

Comment: @RanadipDutta Yes, but i have to check above version,  lower version and same version with extension here -match and -contains not working. i have check only number not build versions

Comment: I don't understand the question.  `$str2 -gt $str1` is `$true`..

Answer (score 2):

Using the frame of [MehmetSeckin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56789157/6811411)s answer but

- casting the version number to [version] type as suggested by [robdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9902555/robdy)
- checking Major and Minor of the version.
- also checking the Distro string and the suffix.
- output a `[PSCustomObject]`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\27\SO_56788705.ps1
function Compare-UbuntuVersions {
    param(
        [string]$VerString1,
        [string]$VerString2
    )
    $Dist1,[version]$Version1,$Suffix1 = $VerString1 -split ' '
    $Dist2,[version]$Version2,$Suffix2 = $VerString2 -split ' '
    If(($Dist1 -eq $Dist2) -and
       ($Suffix1 -eq $Suffix2) -and
       ($Version1.Major -eq $Version2.Major) -and
       ($Version1.Minor -eq $Version2.Minor)) {
        return $True
    } Else {
        return $False
    }
}

$targetVersion = "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"

$versions = @(
    "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS",
    "Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS",
    "Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS",
    "Ubuntu 16.05 LTS"
)

$versions | ForEach-Object { 
   [PSCustomObject]@{
       Target = $targetVersion
       Version= $_
       Match  = Compare-UbuntuVersions $targetVersion $_
   }
}
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\06\27\SO_56788705.ps1

Target           Version             Match
------           -------             -----
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS     True
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS  True
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   True
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Ubuntu 16.05 LTS    False
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know you can split an array and assignt it into a group of variables like that!

Comment: @MehmetSeckin That's a handy feature, see `$one,$two,$three = "one two three four"  -split ' ',3` Without the limiting `,3` $three would be an array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick method using regular expressions:

```
function Compare-UbuntuVersions {
    param
    (
        [string]$Version1,
        [string]$Version2
    )

    $versionRegex = "(?<Version>\d+\.\d+\.?(\d+)?)";
    if ($Version1 -match $versionRegex)
    {
        $v1 = [version]$matches.Version;
    }
    else
    {
        throw "Invalid version string";
    }

    if ($Version2 -match $versionRegex)
    {
        $v2 = [version]$matches.Version;
    }
    else
    {
        throw "Invalid version string";
    }

    if($v1 -gt $v2)
    {
        Write-Host "$Version1 is greater than $Version2";
        return 1;
    }
    elseif ($v1 -eq $v2) 
    {
        Write-Host "$Version1 is equal to $Version2";
        return 0;
    }
    elseif ($v1 -lt $v2) 
    {
        Write-Host "$Version1 is less than $Version2";
        return 0;
    }
}

$targetVersion = "16.04";
$versions = @(
    "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS",
    "Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS",
    "Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS",
    "Ubuntu 16.05 LTS"
)

$versions | % { $null = Compare-UbuntuVersions $_ $targetVersion }

# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is equal to 16.04
# Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS is greater than 16.04
# Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS is greater than 16.04
# Ubuntu 16.05 LTS is greater than 16.04
```